# ASP.NET Core 2.1: Razor Pages - role based authorisation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

My Razor Pages app is configured as follows. Startup.cs contains:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => 
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole("Admin"));
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/About", "RequireAdminRole");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I have a user with the "Admin" role. When the user is logged in and accesses the "About" page, I get the following:

> Access denied
>
> You do not have access to this resource.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

If I remove the `AuthorizePage` and use `GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin")` in the `About.cshtml.cs` page `OnGet` method, then output the `UserName` property in the `About.cshtml` page, the admin user is displayed. So, not sure why the `AuthorizePage` is not working.

UPDATE 29-May-2017

My source code is in this [Github Resository](https://github.com/mrboring-public/asp.net-core-2.1-roles-issue)

Comment: And the user is assigned the Admin role in the aspnetuserroles?  Also, double-check that the casing in the aspnetroles table is the same because it's case-sensitive

Comment: @JasonRoner, Yes the user and role are mapped in AspNetUserRoles. I've tried RequireRole("Admin") (Name) and RequireRole("ADMIN") (NormalizedName), neither worked. I know at least part of the role manager is working as I used it to seed the admin user and role.

Comment: Are you certain the user is authenticated? What does `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` produce?

Comment: @Brad, For both the OnGet and About.cshtml, HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true.

Comment: How is the role being loaded into `HttpContext.User`?  If you remove the authorization policy and then go to About what do you get for `User.IsInRole("Admin")`?

Comment: @Brad, I don't know how the roles are being loaded into `HttpContext.User`. In fact, I can't see any roles hanging off the user. 

I assumed that ASP.NET Core would take care of this after I added `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`. In the documentation the descirption is: _Adds Role related services for TRole, including IRoleStore, IRoleValidator, and RoleManager._

Also, `User.IsInRole("Admin")` and `User.IsInRole("ADMIN")` both return false.

Comment: What authentication are you using?  You don't have a `services.AddAuthentication();` section.

Comment: @Brad, I've put my code in a Github repo (see the update at the bottom of my question). For authentication I'm using `AddDefaultIdentity`. I think this is new.

Comment: Where is the code to actually log the user in? I don't see anything in github. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @LeeGunn, In ASP.NET Core 2.1 they use Razor UI libraries for Identity. All the UI is in a library. Take a look at: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/04/12/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview2-now-available/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddDefaultUI()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I think it works as follows:

- AddItentity - Sets up identity.
- AddDefaultUI - Use new Razor Class Library UI.
- AddDefaultTokenProviders - Needed for two factor authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You must put `.UseAuthentication()` before `.UseMvc()`

`app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();`

I lost a lot of hair because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Please change these lines of your code and try again.
Thank you

```
        //Old
        /*services
            .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            */

        //New
        services
            .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: This does not work. I think it's related to ASP.NET Core 2.1 using a Razor library for the Identity. I think that requires `AddDefaultIdentity`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers did not work for me but after reading this on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813) i changed the code from using Alan T's solution.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
 .AddDefaultUI()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

To this

```
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext>()
          .AddDefaultUI();
```

the    `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext>()`    needs to come after the `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()`

It works perfectly. I am not using TWO factor authentication so i dont need the `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()`

Hopefully it will help someone else who had the same issue i had with roles.